# Fréchet derivative of the total variation norm for measures on a manifold

Tags: non-convex-optimization, frechet-derivative, borel-measures, compact-manifolds, total-variation

Let $\Theta$ be a compact $d$-dimensional [Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) [without boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold) and $M(\Theta)$ (resp. $M_+(\Theta)$) denote the set of signed (resp. nonnegative) finite [Borel measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_measure) on $\Theta$.

> What is the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) of the [total variation norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Modern_definition_of_total_variation_norm) given below?
> $$
> \| \cdot \|_{\text{TV}} \colon M(\Theta) \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \qquad
> \mu \mapsto \| \mu \|_{\text{TV}}
> $$
> Is it even differentiable in $\mu = 0$?

**Context:** in the paper [L. Chizat - Sparse Optimization on Measures with Over-parametrized Gradient Descent](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-021-01636-z) the following setting (A1) is considered:
Let $F$ be a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) and $\phi \colon \Theta \to F$ and $R \colon F \to \mathbb{R}$ each be twice [Fréchet differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) with [locally Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Definitions) second order derivatives such that $\nabla R$ is bounded on sublevel sets.
(Does this mean on the sublevel sets of $R$?)

Chizat claims on page 5 that

> the objective
> \begin{equation*}
> J \colon M_+(\Theta) \to \mathbb R, \qquad
>     \nu \mapsto R\left(\int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \text{d}\nu(\theta)\right) + \lambda \| \nu \|_{\text{TV}},
> \end{equation*}
> which can easily be extended to $M(\Theta)$ (see Appendix A in that paper, which is also available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10300)), is [Fréchet differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) and its differential at $\nu \in M(\Theta)$ can be represented by
> $$
> J^{'}_{\nu} \colon \Theta \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad
> \theta \mapsto \left\langle \phi(\theta), \nabla R\left(\int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \text{d}\nu(\theta)\right) \right\rangle_{F} + \lambda
> $$
> in the sense that $\frac{d}{d \varepsilon} J(\nu + \varepsilon \sigma) \bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int_{\Theta} J_{\nu}^{'}(\theta) \text{d}\sigma(\theta)$.

Using that the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) is linear and just focussing on the second term (with $\lambda$), this would imply that $D \| \cdot \|_{\text{TV}}(\nu)[\sigma] = \| \sigma \|_{\text{TV}}$, where $D f(x)[h] \in Y$ is the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) of $f \colon X \to Y$ at $x \in X$ in direction $h \in X$.

> We have that if $f$ is linear, then $D f(x)[h] = f(h)$ for all $x, h \in X$.
> Does the converse also hold? If yes, this would imply that the total variation norm is linear, which is surely not true.

Comment: @RozaTh Thank you for your reply. By the last sentence you mean that $\frac{d}{d \nu} \nu(\Theta) = 1$? And for $\nu \in M_+(\Theta)$ we have $\| \nu \|_{\text{TV}} = \nu(\Theta)$, right?

Comment: @RozaTh I thought that $J$ in formula (1) was only defined on $M_+(\Theta)$ for sake of simplicity of presentation and that the general case to consider was on $M(\Theta)$, but I now realise that the minimisation in (1) covers the case of signed measures and then on p. 5 we nonetheless consider $J$ as a functional on $M(\Theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written here is inconsistent with what I remembered from the paper. So I followed both links (Springer & arXiv). Your definition for $J$ here is not what's in the paper.

First, $J$ in page 5 of arXiv or 6 of Springer is defined on $M$ not $M_+$ ($M_+$ would be wrong here since it's not a vector space but $M$ is.) It's the optimization that is over $M_+$.

Second, the last term in $J$ is the total mass $\nu(\Theta)$ not $||\nu||$. The norm in a Banach space is not in general Fréchet differentiable. There it is differentiating $\nu\mapsto \nu(\Theta)$, not the total variation $\nu\mapsto ||\nu||$, w.r.t to $\nu$, which is 1. That is for $J(\nu)=\nu(\Theta)=\int_\Theta d\nu(\Theta)$, $J$ is linear on $M$ so its derivative is itself; $dJ_\nu(\sigma)=\sigma(\Theta)=\int_\Theta 1 d\sigma(\Theta)$, compare that with the definition of $J'_\nu(\Theta)$, you get $J'_\nu(\Theta)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One small thing: do you know what "$\nabla R$ is bounded on sublevel sets" is supposed to mean? I only know sublevel sets for functions mapping into the real numbers, but the standard example of $R$ is $R(f) := \frac{1}{2} \| f -f^*\|_{\mathcal F}^{2}$, which has derivative $\nabla R(f) = f - f^*$ and if $R \colon \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}$, then $\nabla R$ does not have to map into the reals, right?

Comment: @Ramanujan I can only guess to that based on how it is used.The sublevel set assumption is used in the last three lines of the proof of Lemma 2.5. We want $\sup_{J(ν)\leq J(ν_k)} ‖J'(ν)‖_{\mathcal{C}^2}$ to be finite. Now Eq.(3) gives part of $J'(ν)$ as inner product with $\nabla R(\int \phi(\theta)dν)$. So basically what you need is for the norm of $\nabla R(\int \phi(\theta)dν)\in \mathcal{F}$ to be bounded for all $ν$ such that $J(ν)\leq J(ν_k)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!