# $\int J_{\nu^*}' \text{d}(\nu - \nu^*) \ge 0$ for all $\nu \in M$ if and only if $J_{\nu^*}' \ge 0$ and $J_{\nu^*}' \equiv 0$ on $\text{supp}(\nu^*)$.

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> On page 11 of [Lenaic Chizat - Sparse Optimization on Measures with Over-parametrized Gradient Descent](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-021-01636-z) (available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10300)) in the proof of proposition 3.1, it is claimed that under several assumptions (see below) the following are equivalent for a $\nu^* \in M := M_+(\Theta)$ (a finite nonnegative measure on $\Theta$ with finite mass $\nu^*(\Theta) < \infty$)
>
> 1. $J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \ge 0$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$ and $J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) = 0$ if $\theta \in \text{supp}(\nu^*)$.
> 2. $\int_{\Theta} J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \text{d}(\nu - \nu^*)(\theta) \ge 0$ for all $\nu \in M$. (Note that this means that $-J_{\nu^*}'$ has to be in the normal cone of $M$ at $\nu^*$.)

Here $(F, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ is a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) $\Theta$ is a compact $d$-dimensional [Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Definition) without boundary, $\phi \colon \Theta \to F$ and $R \colon F \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ are twice [Fréchet differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) and have [locally Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Definitions) second-order derivatives.
Further, $\nabla R$ is bounded on [sublevel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Sublevel_and_superlevel_sets) and $R$ is convex. (What exactly the sublevel boundedness and differentiability mean is adressed in these [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427813/fr%c3%a9chet-derivative-of-the-total-variation-norm-for-measures-on-a-manifold) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4429166/derivative-of-a-function-from-a-closed-riemannian-manifold-to-a-hilbert-space) of mine.)
Lastly,
$$
J(\nu)
:= R\left(\int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \text{d}{\nu}(\theta)\right) + \lambda \nu(\Theta)
$$
for $\nu \in M$, $\lambda > 0$ and for $\theta \in \Theta$
$$
J_{\nu}'(\theta)
= \left\langle \phi(\theta), \nabla R\left(\int_{\Theta} \phi(\theta) \text{d}\nu(\theta)\right) \right\rangle_{F} + \lambda.
$$
is a representation of the gradient of $J$ at $\nu$.

#### My question

I can show that 1. $\implies$ 2. and that if $J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \ge 0$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$, then 2. $\implies$ 1.
But I am struggling to show that 2. implies that $J_{\nu^*}'$ is nonnegative, could anybody please give me a hint?

---

#### The proofs I have got so far

"1 $\implies$ 2":
Suppose $\nu^* \in M_+(\Theta)$ fulfills 1.
Then for any $\nu \in M_+(\Theta)$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Theta} J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \text{d}{(\nu - \nu^*)}(\theta)
= \int_{\Theta \setminus \text{supp}(\nu^*)} J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \text{d}{(\nu - \nu^*)}(\theta) 
= \int_{\Theta \setminus \text{supp}(\nu^*)} \underbrace{J_{\nu^*}'(\theta)}_{\ge 0} \text{d}{\nu}(\theta)
\ge 0.
\end{align*}

"2 $\impliedby$ 1":
Suppose 2. holds.
*If $J_{\nu^*}' \ge 0$ on $\Theta$*, then taking $\nu$ to be the zero measure, we get
\begin{equation*}
0
\ge \int_{\Theta} J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \text{d}{\nu^*(\theta)}
= \int_{\text{supp}(\nu^*)} J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \text{d}{\nu^*(\theta)},
\end{equation*}
so we must have $J_{\nu^*}' \equiv 0$ on $\text{supp}(\nu^*)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $\nu := \nu^* + \delta_{\theta_0}$ for some $\theta_0 \in \Theta$. Then by assumption
$$
0 
\overset{2.}{\le} \int_{\Theta} J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \text{d}(\nu - \nu^*)(\theta)
= \int_{\Theta} J_{\nu^*}'(\theta) \text{d}\delta_{\theta_0}(\theta)
= J_{\nu^*}'(\theta_0),
$$
so $J_{\nu^*}'(\theta_0) \ge 0$, implying the nonnegativity of $J_{\nu^*}'$.

---

Notice that this does not depend on how $J_{\nu^*}'$ looks like and hence we have actually proved the elegant characterisation
$$
N_{M_+(\Theta)}(\nu^*)
= \left\{ f \in \mathcal{C}(\Theta; \mathbb{R}): f \le 0, \ f|_{\text{supp} (\nu^*)} \equiv 0 \right\},
$$
where $N_C(x)$ is the normal cone of $C$ at $x$.